# Why do I have a -2 rep today for "User was removed"

Tags: support, reputation

I saw in the reputation dropdown a -2 for this site.

On inspection my reputation tab looks as follows. Both of my positive reputation entries come from approved edits - how can these be affected by user removal?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited a post as a low-rep user.

That suggested edit was approved and you earned 2 rep for that.

Now a relatively low-rep user account was deleted and the rep-gain for the approved edit was reversed, as it was approved by that now removed other user.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26077
seems to be the post in question?

Approval now owned by "Community♦ reviewed this Jan 2 '17 at 16:23: Approve"

As explained here, on Meta.Stackexchange: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

> The account of a user who was the final approver of a suggested edit you made has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as User was removed): −2

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware of that possibility